# How to store checks of gradient algorithm in a matrix using R?

Tags: r

I would like to check different gradient algorithms. For example:

```
 fr <- function(x) {   ## Rosenbrock Banana function
         x1 <- x[1]
         x2 <- x[2]
        print(c(x1,x2))
         100 * (x2 - x1 * x1)^2 + (1 - x1)^2
     }
optim(c(-1.2,1),fr,method="BFGS")
```

prints to the screen the values at which the RBF has been evaluated.

How can I store these values in a matrix ? (instead of just printing them to the screen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function **capture.output**:

```
cc<-capture.output(vv<-optim(c(-1.2,1),fr,method="BFGS"))
t(sapply(strsplit(gsub(" +"," ",cc)," "),function(l)as.numeric(l[2:3])))
```

The variable `vv` is used so that the result of optim will not be printed only your calls to the function. Each call to the function results in one element of `cc`. Then I strip extra spaces, so that I can split the strings with the space. Afterwards you simply select what is needed.

This solution will work if optim produces errors, but I think it is not very hard to adapt the code to guard against that.

This is of course only the quick hack. For more complicated solutions you will need to delve into the code of optim.

@onestop suggested using **sink**, it is more simple:

```
sink("bu.txt")
vv<-optim(c(-1.2,1),fr,method="BFGS")
sink()
read.table("bu.txt")
```

Note the additional `sink`, so that the output is diverted again to the console.

Comment: @onestop, why did you delete your answer? I was just about ready to upvote it.

Comment: (+1) Let's say my vote goes to both of you :-)